# accessing fscanf() in c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am using C++(MFC) dll in my C# application. My application getting closed when i tried to access `fstream()` function (from DLL )with different specifier. sample code is given here:

```
fscanf(fp,"%1c",&colon);       // this works fine
fscanf(fp,"%2x",&byte_count);  // My application got closed.
```

But it will work fine if i execute my C++ application individually, and not able to call it if i use through dll in my c# application. It is not throwing any error or exception(since the method is in DLL). But simply getting closed. Can anybody give the solution?? or any idea to figure out the log file generated to find out the errors??

thanks,

Vinod

Answer (score 0):

take a look of the following code:

```
int c=-1;
cout<<"enter 1:";   
scanf("%c",&c);
cout<<hex<<c<<endl;
c=-1; 
cout<<"enter 1:";
scanf("%2x",&c);
cout<<hex<<c<<endl;
```

It gives the result:

```
enter 1:1
ffffff31 <-- you wrote only 1 byte which is good
enter 1:1
1 <--- means you wrote 4 bytes.
```

If byte_count is not 32 bit int.

It will be treated as 32 bit integer so you may run over the following variable, and it absolutely may be the reason for the crash.

You better use the c++ object, `ifstream`, to read from the file.

Comment: both colon and byte_count is a type of unsigned char. and they are working if i called directly in C++ application. And giving an error if i do through c# application. But through C# application also its fine if comment second line "fscanf(fp,"%2x",&byte_count);"

Comment: Undefined behavior is funny like that, it just _appears_ to work in one instance and not another. Either change `byte_count` to an `int` or create a temporary `int` to do the read then assign it to `byte_count`. Accept it and move on, you can't fight UB and win.

Comment: If you wrote only 1 byte, how do you explain 4 bytes was changed? the reason it is sometimes works is because of the alignment.

Comment: Also c# variables are marshaled, means any overflow is detected immediately. that is the reason for the immediate crash in c#,

Comment: Thank you all for your support. I got a solution. There was a mismatch in datatype. For character i was trying it as %2X. It was wrong. I changed to Unsigned long. Now its working